# NPM errors when running mrt add kadira

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, meteor

when trying to run mrt add kadira I get this error. I can add other packages fine such as iron-router or collectionFS, not sure what's causing the issue. I have tried updating my version of npm but that didn't seem to do much. Anyone have any ideas?

```
kadira: updating npm dependencies -- debug, usage...
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/usage
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/usage
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings
Usage: gyp_main.py [options ...] [build_file ...]

gyp_main.py: error: no such option: --no-parallel
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit     (/home/theostyles/.meteor/tools/858c88b520/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-    gyp/lib/configure.js:340:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:807:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-29-generic
gyp ERR! command "node"     "/home/theostyles/.meteor/tools/858c88b520/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-    gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd     /home/theostyles/.meteorite/packages/kadira/meteorhacks/kadira/6073fa5bdfb36478165977804f92    2796b6fc82de/.npm/package-new-1dwhr1e/node_modules/usage
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.28
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! usage@0.4.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the usage@0.4.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the usage package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls usage
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-29-generic
npm ERR! command "/home/theostyles/.meteor/tools/858c88b520/bin/node"     "/home/theostyles/.meteor/tools/858c88b520/bin/npm" "install" "usage@0.4.3"
npm ERR! cwd     /home/theostyles/.meteorite/packages/kadira/meteorhacks/kadira/6073fa5bdfb36478165977804f92    2796b6fc82de/.npm/package-new-1dwhr1e
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!         /home/theostyles/.meteorite/packages/kadira/meteorhacks/kadira/6073fa5bdfb36478165977804f92    2796b6fc82de/.npm/package-new-1dwhr1e/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

=> Errors while scanning packages:

While building package `kadira`:
error: couldn't install npm package

    /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/command.js:41
        throw "Command exited with " + code + "/" + signal;
                                                  ^
    Command exited with 1/null
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is a problem with a binary npm dependency of Kadira and has been reported in the following issue:

> https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2249

It should be fixed shortly.